# Get all the rows with rownames starting with ABC111

Tags: r

We have the following data frame :

```
           col1 col2 col3       
ABC111001  12   12    13 
ABC111002  3    4    5 
ABC000111  7    6    1
ABC000112  9    23   1
```

How to get all the rows with rownames started with "**ABC111**" as follows:

```
ABC111001  12  12  13 
ABC111002  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use e.g. `substr` or `grepl`:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=" ", text="col1 col2 col3 
ABC111001 12 12 13 
ABC111002 3 4 5 
ABC000111 7 6 1
ABC000112 9 23 1")

needle <- "ABC111"
i <- substr(row.names(df), 0, nchar(needle))==needle
i <- grepl(paste0("^", needle), row.names(df))
df[i,]
#           col1 col2 col3
# ABC111001   12   12   13
# ABC111002    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 5):

Given the sample data:

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=" ", text="x col1 col2 col3
ABC111001 12 12 13
ABC111002 3 4 5
ABC000111 7 6 1
ABC000112 9 23 1")
```

... you can select matching rows using `grep`:

```
> data[grep('^ABC111', rownames(data)),]
          col1 col2 col3
ABC111001   12   12   13
ABC111002    3    4    5
```