# Remove rows with NA.x as row number in R

Tags: r, row, na

Apologies for not providing a mock data set, but here is a screen shot of my problem:

[image]

What you're seeing is a subset of my dataframe. I am trying to remove the rows that have `NA, NA.1, NA.x ...NA.6` in the actual row numbers from my dataframe.

I have tried going back to my original .csv files and deleting the ~200 blank rows under where my data ends, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: `grepl("^NA", rownames(DF))` is the core of what you're after

Comment: If you delete the csv rows in a text editor instead of Excel, that might work. Otherwise, if you know how many rows you should have, `n`, just filter to that like `DF[1:n, ]`

Comment: df[ ! (rownames(df) %in% c('NA.1', 'NA.2', 'NA.3', 'NA.4', 'NA.5', 'NA.6' )), ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all the rows with rownames starting with ABC111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825689/get-all-the-rows-with-rownames-starting-with-abc111)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on MichaelChirico's comment and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825797/8712471).

```
df <- df[grepl("^NA", rownames(df))==F,]
```

This creates a new `df` without any rows that have `NA` in their names. Any row that does have a rowname of `NA` will be flagged as `TRUE` with the `grep1` command; only the rows that are flagged as `FALSE` are kept.

Answer (score 0):

After being in a R-rabbit hole for hours, I figured out some sort of an answer, although it isn't quite satisfying.

I had tried some options like `DF[!is.na(DF$column_w/_an_NA_that_should_have_data),]` to remove those rows, but I was getting a result of there being no rows with `NA` in the specified column.

I figured out that it had something to do with `merge`. The `data.frame` (DF) I showed you was a merged DF of two DFs of different length. The two DFs differed by 8 rows - exactly the number of weird NA.x columns.

I will call the DF with 240 rows "DFA" and the DF with 232 rows "DFB". I used `DFC <- merge(DFA, DFB, all = T)` to merge the DFs. If I export DFC as a .csv and open it in Excel, everything looks as it should - all the 240 rows are there, and there is a subset of 8 rows that have NAs in DFA-specific columns.

So why are these NA.x rows (i.e., NA.x in row #) showing up when I subset my data? Well, I found that when I subset my data by a column that was common to DFA and DFB, the output looks normal. That is, there are none of the weird NA.x rows. However, when I subset my data by a column that was unique to DFA, the 8 rows for which there are NAs in that column show up as being completely NA.x rows. More specifically, I subsetted a DFA-unique column composed of factors by e.g., 1 of 3 levels. This is when I see the NA.x rows pop up.

I have no clue why the whole row turns into these strange NA.x rows, given that those rows have data in the DFA-DFB common columns and DFB-unique columns.

Have any of you run into a similar phenomenon? The R-wizzes I talked to had never encountered it, and couldn't figure our why that would happen.